# How do I access administrator account from standard user on window 7 if I don't know the password to the administrator account

Tags: windows-7, administrator, lenovo-laptop

Thanks for the help.  I forgot my admin account password and want to log in through standard because its the only one I can access.  any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you had access to a windows 7 disk? This could fix your problem:

1) Boot with windows 7 disk and click on "Repair your computer".

2) Wait to the program to found your windows install. Take note of the drive letter found in the Location column. Most Windows 7 installations will show D: but yours may be different.

3) Select Windows 7 , click next button.

4) From System Recovery Options, choose Command Prompt. Then execute this commands:

copy d:\windows\system32\utilman.exe d:\ (or C: or whatever you note on step 2)

copy d:\windows\system32\cmd.exe d:\windows\system32\utilman.exe

To the Overwrite question after executing the second command, answer with Yes.

5) Remove disk and reboot

6) On  Windows 7 logon screen, locate the little icon on the bottom-left of the screen that looks like a pie with a square around it and then click it!

7) Will appears Command Prompt again, execute the net user command as shown, replacing myusername with whatever your user name is and mypassword with whatever new password you'd like to use:

net user myusername mypassword

Tip: If your username has spaces, put double quotes around it when executing net user, as in net user "Tim Fisher" 1lov3blueberrie$.

8)Close the Command Prompt window and login with your new password

Comment: It is good practice on the Super User site to include most important parts of the linked page. Should linked page become inaccessible the data will be available here. So, please, provide more data rather than single link.